# Copying file in selected directory by directory Chooser

Tags: java, javafx

I want to copy a file in a directory which will be selected by directory chooser. For doing so I have tried..

```
    DirectoryChooser di = new DirectoryChooser();
    File src = new File("C:/Users/ir.emon/Desktop/dump1.png");
    File dest = di.showDialog(null);
    try {
        Files.copy(src.toPath(), dest.toPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this always gives "`java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException`" though the file I wanted to copy doesn't exist in the desired directory chose by directory chooser. I also tried adding the `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` option. But in that case the target (destination) folder is being corrupted. Can anyone please help me regarding this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)):

> target - the path to the target *file* (may be associated with a different provider to the source path)

You didn't supplied a file as target but the containing directory. So the behaviour of your code is fully plausible.

Change your code as follows:

```
Files.copy(src.toPath(), new File(dest, "deservedFilename.ext").toPath());
```